# How to exit from outer IF statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

How to exit from the outer IF statement, and continue the stored procedure

```
IF (true) THEN

    -- do some work here

    IF (somethingWrong=true) THEN
        -- Exit from the outer IF and continue SP
    END IF;

    -- do some work here
END IF;
```

Comment: The way you have the code now, execution will any way exit the outer `IF` block, whether the inner condition is true or not. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: `IF (somethingWrong==true) THEN` `==` does not exist in MySQL ( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e01/441 ) you need to use `=` to check equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just test the opposite condition:

```sql
IF (true) THEN
    /* do some work here */
    IF (NOT somethingWrong) THEN
        /* Do whatever is remaining to do in this outer IF block */
    END IF;
END IF;
```

In case you have multiple instances where you want to bail out like that, then you probably don't want to nest the `IF` blocks like this:

```
IF (true) THEN
    /* do some work here */
    IF (NOT somethingWrong) THEN
        /* do some more work here */
        IF (NOT somethingWrong) THEN
            /* Do whatever is remaining to do in this outer IF block */
        END;
    END IF;
END IF;
```

... this can get deeply nested. Instead use a variable (check the [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html) syntax) that keeps track of the error condition and flatten your `IF`s. Something like this:

```
SET err = 0
IF (true) THEN
    /* do some work here */
    IF (NOT err)
        /* do some more work here that maybe sets the err variable to some non-zero value */
    END IF;
    IF (NOT err)
        /* do some more work here that maybe sets the err variable non-zero */
    END IF;
    IF (NOT err)
        /* do the remaining work */
    END IF;
END IF;
```

You can even have some loops with the same principle in there:

```
IF (true) THEN
    /* do some work here */
    IF (NOT err)
        /* do some more work here that maybe sets the err variable to some non-zero value */
    END IF;
    IF (NOT err)
        /* do some more work here that maybe sets the err variable non-zero */
    END IF;
    WHILE (NOT err AND some_loop_condition) DO
        /* some work that needs to repeat a few times, 
           but should be interrupted when err is non-zero */
    END WHILE
    IF (NOT err)
        /* do the remaining work */
    END IF;
END IF;
```